# Collect values of checkboxes and use said values to automatically check boxes in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
<% if !result.platforms.nil? %>
<div class="platforms">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<% result.platforms.each do |platform| %>
<label class="btn btn-default">
<input type="checkbox" name="options" class="platbtn" value= <%=platform.id %> ><%= platform["name"] %></label>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

...

```
<% result.platforms.each do |platform| %>
<span class='select_platform'>
<%= check_box_tag "game[platforms][id][]", platform.id %>
<%= label_tag "game[platforms][name][]", platform.name %>
</span>
<% end %>
```

This code turns into...

```
<span class="select_platform">
<input id="game_platforms_id_" name="game[platforms][id][]" type="checkbox" value="19">
<label for="game_platforms_name_">Game Boy Advance</label>
</span>
```

Okay, with this, I would like to take the values (the platform_id) of the buttons/checkboxes I push/check in the #platforms div and automatically check the corresponding boxes in the span class "select-platform".

I have tried numerous different ways of grabbing values of said boxes but when I go to view the array, nothing is inside. I'm not sure if I'm just simply asking for the values the wrong way in both cases or what.

The last way I tried to grab and store values was with this code snippet found elsewhere on stack overflow.

```
var values = $('input:checkbox:checked.platbtn').map(function() {
return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: I've tried numerous jQuery code snippets from here. I'm pretty new to this jquery thing, so I'm sure I'm probably messing up somewhere :)

Comment: show us one that might be helpful to answer.

Comment: I just added one. That will only get the values from said checkboxes, nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to know how to identify each checkbox inside the span. As you are using the id to pass the values as parameters, an easy way is to use the class attribute like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "game[platforms][id][]", platform.id, false, class: platform.id  %>
```

This way you can access this checkbox by using `$('.your_id')`, so you attach an change event on all of the platforms checkboxes like this:

```
$(".platforms input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
  var selected = $(this).val(); // This will get the value
  $("."+selected).prop('checked', 'checked'); // This will check the box
});
```

Comment: One step further, I noticed that it checks all boxes that match the id from all my results. Is there a way to narrow that scope down to just that one result? `<input id="game_game_id" name="game[game_id]" type="hidden" value="2094">`

Comment: You can take a look at JQuery `.first()` method.

Comment: One last thing: What about toggling? Right now if I depress my button, the checkbox remains checked and vice versa.

Comment: You can add a verification: `if ($(this).is(":checked"))`. If this is `false`, then you just `prop('checked', '')`. Also, i would be glad if you could vote up the answer too. =]

Comment: I would vote it up as hard as I could if I had the rep!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Didn't know.

Comment: It's okay! Uh, so I have 

'if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $("."+selected).first().prop('checked', 'checked'); // This will check the box
    else
    $("."+selected).prop('checked', false);
    });`  

Things seem to work great, except that when I click some buttons, it will check the box on the game above it instead of the one it should check below!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that checkbox doesn't have `value` so you should store your value in html data-attribute.
Also you have to wrap `this` with jQuery.

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options" class="platbtn" data-value= <%=platform.id %> >
```

js

```
$(':checked.platbtn').map(function(){ return $(this).data('value');}).get();
```